# Laravel Job does not work to eager load relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Job in Laravel, something like this:

```php
class ProcessStockLevel implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;
    
    public function handle()
    {
        $productsDb = Product::with('inStock')->whereNull('order_id')->get(); 
    }
}
```

but `$productDb->inStock` is always null. When I run this code outside queque ewerything works as expected. What is wrong with eager load in queues?

Comment: Did you try php artisan queue:listen?
I wonder if the instance in the queue is old hence not working the updated code.

Comment: @AbdurRahman listen behaves the same way. I am always restarting process after code update :(

Comment: Does it work if you remove eager loading?

Comment: Yes it works. But calling $productDb->inStocks()->get() in foreach is killing my DB.

Comment: Can you show the inStocks relation function?
Also,
$productDb->inStocks()->get()
try $productDb->inStocks

Now I am confused if the relation name is inStocks or inStock?
Please check that.

Comment: public function inStock()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPiece', 'product_id')->whereNotNull('location_id');
    }

Its inStock, inStocks was typo.